# How to print scientific notation with all significant digits moved after decimal point in python

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision, scientific-notation

I am trying to print scientific numbers with all the significant digits after the decimal point. `

Python's scientific notation prints with one digit before the dot like `1.2345678E+03`,

```
'%E' % Decimal('1234.5678')
'1.2345678E+03'
```

but I want to print `0.12345E+04` instead.

Edit:
A more generalized approach to have arbitrary number of digits before and after the dot would be more helpful. Like being able to print `123.456E+01` or `1234.56E-01` etc.

Comment: `1.2345678E+03 / 10E+03`

Comment: I'm not aware of anything built in, so you'll probably have to write your own code to do this.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest This gives a decimal number. Converting it back to scientific notation would again move one significant digit before the dot. A more generalized approach to have arbitrary number of digits before and after the dot would be more helpful. e.g. `123.456E+01` or `1234.56E-01` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python scientific notation with forced leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266850/python-scientific-notation-with-forced-leading-zero)

Comment: @vishes_shell any suggestions about the edit?

Comment: Check the link, of @vishes_shell. As what you want is not the standard scientific representation, there is no built in way to format the way you want it.